# Calculating the distance For each Row with respect to a Common Point

Tags: python, postgis, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have two models with no relation `Port` and a `WareHouse` each with a `lat` and `long` fields. I want to be able to get the distance for each warehouse from the Port and maybe get the closest e.t.c.

This is part the error:

```
InternalError: (psycopg2.errors.InternalError_) parse error - invalid geometry
HINT:  "POINT(Wa" <-- parse error at position 8 within geometry

[SQL: SELECT warehouse.created_at AS warehouse_created_at, warehouse.updated_at AS warehouse_updated_at, warehouse.id AS warehouse_id, warehouse.name AS warehouse_name, warehouse.latitude AS warehouse_latitude, warehouse.longitude AS warehouse_longitude, warehouse.obs_lab_id AS warehouse_obs_lab_id, ST_Distance(Geometry(ST_GeomFromText(%(ST_GeomFromText_1)s)), Geometry(ST_GeomFromText(%(ST_GeomFromText_2)s))) AS distance 
FROM warehouse ORDER BY distance 
 LIMIT %(param_1)s]
[parameters: {'ST_GeomFromText_1': 'POINT(-10.8698502 9.3450003)', 'ST_GeomFromText_2': 'POINT(Warehouse.longitude Warehouse.latitude)', 'param_1': 1}]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/2j85)
```

How should I go about it? This is what I currently have.

```
 port = session.query(Port).first()

 warehouse_distances = session.query(
     Warehouse,
     func.ST_Distance(
         func.Geometry(func.ST_GeomFromText(f"POINT({port.longitude} {fac.latitude})")),
      func.Geometry(
            func.ST_GeomFromText(f"POINT({Warehouse.longitude} {Warehouse.latitude})")
        )
    ).label("distance"),
 ).order_by("distance")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like 'port.longitude' and 'fac.latitude' are correctly replaced in your f-string, but 'Warehouse.longitude' and 'Warehouse.latitude' are not and are left as string. The reason is you try to create a geom from text so the input is a string, not columns.

If you want to create a geom from fields you should use for example the function [ST_MakePoint](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html) and pass your 2 columns as parameters.

Comment: This worked easier than expected